# Why does `get_or_create` execute expression from defaults when object is found?

Tags: django

```
lang_group = 'en'
for place_category in place['categories']:
        translation, created = \
            PlaceTypesTranslations.objects.get_or_create(
                name=place_category, lang_group=lang_group,
                    defaults={'place_type_group': PlaceTypesGroups.objects.create()})
```

In this case if the loop has 1000 iterations and, for example, 500 times `created=True` and other 500 times `created=False`, anyway will be created 1000 `PlaceTypesGroups`, so for some reason even if `get_or_create` returns `get`, `defaults` anyway is executed.

The same algorithm, but different approach:

```
lang_group = 'en'
for place_category in place['categories']:
    if PlaceTypesTranslations.objects.filter(name=place_category, lang_group=lang_group).exists():
        place_cat_trans = PlaceTypesTranslations.objects.get(name=place_category, lang_group=lang_group)
        place_group = place_cat_trans.place_type_group
    else:
        place_group = PlaceTypesGroups.objects.create()
        place_cat_trans = PlaceTypesTranslations.objects.create(name=place_category,
                                                                lang_group=lang_group,
                                                                place_type_group=place_group)
```

In this case just 500 times will be created `PlaceTypesGroups` as expected.
Why is that? What I do not see in the 1st case? Why does `get_or_create` creates 1000 `PlaceTypesGroups`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's called 1000x, because you are assigning the returned value from the function. I'll start with a simple example:

```
place_type_group = some_function()
```

The variable now contains whatever the function returns, right?

Now if you wrap it into a dictionary, it's still the same thing, just wrapper into a dictionary:

```
dict(place_type_group = some_function())
```

the element in a dict still contains the value returned from `some_function()`

The dictionary above is just equal for the following code, which is what you do in your code (ie. assigning function return value into a variable)

```
{'place_type_group': some_function() }
```

Comment: Ok. I got it. I thought for some reason, that `defaults` part is executed just in case if `get` can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way Python expressions always work. Anything inside an expression must always be fully evaluated before the expression itself can be passed to a function or method.

However, Django specifically lets you pass a *callable*, rather than a value, in the `defaults` hash. So you can do:

```
      PlaceTypesTranslations.objects.get_or_create(
            name=place_category, lang_group=lang_group,
                defaults={'place_type_group': PlaceTypesGroups.objects.create})
```

and it will call the `create` method as required.

Comment: this does not work -> `ValueError: Cannot assign "<bound method BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method of <django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x7f0b7928e080>>": "PlaceTypesTranslations.place_type_group" must be a "PlaceTypesGroups" instance.`